# Is it wrong for a question to be wrong?

Tags: discussion

Off topic and useless questions aside, what about questions that have an incorrect premise? Every question makes some assumptions. Does the question need to be closed when those assumptions are wrong?

Examples:

- [Why are logs not used for testing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/448928/131624)
- [How to be (more) critical during Code Reviews of team members?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/448943/131624)
- [Why is it necessary to mark classes as not inherited from? Can't an optimizer automatically detect that virtual calls are unnecessary?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/447860/why-is-it-necessary-to-mark-classes-as-not-inherited-from-cant-an-optimizer-au)
- [Why are Service Locator frameworks often called Dependency Injection Containers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/415157/131624)

These questions have comments complaining about the assumptions they are making and/or answers that reject some assumption it made. Is it better to close such questions or better to provide answers that reject the faulty premise of the question?

It may be worth considering another meta post: [What's a frame challenge?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how having incorrect assumptions would result in a question being closed, assuming that it's otherwise on-topic and useful/helpful. If the person asking the question made incorrect assumptions in their reasoning, then it's likely that other people have also made incorrect assumptions and addressing those could be helpful. It should be up to the answerer to address those incorrect assumptions, since an assumption may not be universally invalid and an answer may rely on an assumption of uncertain validity.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong assumptions alone don't make a question off-topic or unfocussed. But quite often questions with wrong premises or wrong assumptions come with other weaknesses which justify closage. The first two questions you cited are clearly examples for this.

I cannot speak for the other voters, but I voted to close the [first question on your list](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/448928/why-are-logs-not-used-for-testing) because the core statement was looking so wrong for me that I thought *"that literal question is surely not really what the OP meant"*. It gave me the impression of being worded in a way it would easily cause wild opinionated guesses of what the OP really had in mind. The OP in between admitted they did not express themselves well and expressed their intention to improve the question - still they did not fix it yet, four days after the closage.

The second one was not critized because of making wrong assumptions, but because of the (probably wrong) impression the OP was going to judge their team members in a code review. When told, the author fixed that (which means your citation of the title in your meta question isn't correct any more, btw.). Me (and others) voted the question up afterwards. Still, a diamond mod closed the question as "too opinonated" (which I can perfectly understand when reading the very different answers the question got).

The third and the fourth one were well received by the community, I don't have the impression they got any close votes for having an incorrect premise.

So in short, a wrong premise or wrong assumption alone is not a valid reason for closing a question - but also not a reason to keep it open. And quite often fixing a wrong premise in a question can help to avoid opinionated discussions.